# d3 - help required in hierarchical bar

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xW66Q/1/).

I have two columns with numbers namely `value` and `count`.

I managed to add the `count` as data label as it's been binded to `.value` of the hierarchy function.

Here's the code.

```
bar.append("svg:text")
  .attr("x", -18)
  .attr("y", y / 2)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("class", "y-labels")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name + ' - ' + d.value; });
```

Now I wanted to add the value column too along with the count.

I'm unable to add value column as the hierarchy only referring to the column named `size` through this function.

Column `count` from the data is named as `size` through a function where I convert the flat JSON data to hierarchical data.

```
var hierarchy = d3.layout.partition()
.value(function(d) { return d.size; });
```

Can some one help me in adding the column value along with the count what I've reported in the chart?

Thanks in advance.